# jquery Loader Widget not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery mobile loader widget Via Ajax call, during the function call `LoadingData` it should show the loading mask , but it is not showing any loading mask, once it done it direct pop up the result.

my code is as follow

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
            $.ajax({url: "SomeURL",
                beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
                complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); }, //Hide spinner

                success: function (result) {
                    LoadingData(result);
                },
                error: function (request,error) {
                    alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                }
            });   
        });
```

Is that anything that i left out for using the loader widget ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` and `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` are replaced by `$.mobile.loading('show');` and `$.mobile.loading('hide');` as of **jQuery Mobile 1.3.2**.

However, using them on `pageinit` requires setting time interval until page is fully initialized.

On other events, such as `pagebeforeshow` and `pageshow`, they can be called immediately.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zacK6/)**

Comment: how to do I add this to my ajax ?

Comment: Just replace old functions with new ones stated @abccba

Comment: I replace  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();  with $.mobile.loading('show'); but it is not showing anything.

Comment: @abccba wrap it in setTimeout function, check my demo. If you replace pageinit with pageshow it will work.

Comment: you mean My ajax call also must be inside the setTimeout ?

Comment: No, not your ajax call, just the loading function @abccba